# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list on simple function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(func(){
        newfunc();
    });
});
```

I've seen this is caused by un-escaped quotes...but I'm just trying to replicate a tutorial from the web. Not sure why I'm getting this error on such a simple piece of code.

Comment: change `func` to `function` in line 2  
`$("button").click(func(){` => `$("button").click(function(){`

Comment: Write  `$("button").click(function(){` instead of  `$("button").click(func`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `click(function (){})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `func` to `function`. In the click method you have to pass a callback function. If you have declared earlier a function, pass there a reference to this function. Otherwiser pass an anonymous function like below and define inside it's body, what you want to be executed when the button is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        newfunc();
    });
});
```

By the way **propably** you have also to change your selector, `$("button")`. If the button has a specific id, for instance `buttonId`, then use this: `$("#buttonId")`. While if the button has a specific class, for instance `js-button`, then use this: `$(".js-button")`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        newfunc();
    });
});
```

`func` should be `function`, it is a `function()` execute on click.

Answer (score 0):

You just got simple syntax error; If you ment to use `func`, you don't declare it's body, here's cases

Consider this

```
var func = function(){};

//RIGHT
$("button").click(func); //callback function

//RIGHT
$("button").click(function func(){}); //we just creating new named function, named callback

//RIGHT
$("button").click(function(){}); //anonymous callback function

//WRONG
$("button").click(func(){}); //anonymous callback function
```

Although answer is simple, here's also demo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    function newfunc(elem){
        $(elem).css('background', 'red');
    }
    $("button").click(function(){
        newfunc(this);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click me</button>
```